# Check if specific MessageDialog is showing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to prevent showing 2 `MessageDialog`s at once. So I want to have only one `MessageDialog` and show or hide it as needed. However, I can't find how to check whether it's already shown, and calling `ShowAsync` twice throws an exception.

So how do I check if it's currently shown?

Comment: You could use a `bool` variable to be set `true` when you call your `MessageDialogs `.

Answer (score 1):

In that you (your code) control(s) the display of a dialog it is up to you to track whether it is being displayed.

You could set a flag somewhere in your code whenever the dialog is displayed that you can then check before showing it again.

psuedocode:

```
if (!dialogBeingShown)
{
    dialogBeingShown = true;

    await messageDialog.ShowAsync("alert");
    dialogBeingShown = false;
}
```

However, that you're asking this question suggests that your code is possibly overly complex such that you can get into the situation where different parts of the app may want to show messages at the same time. If this is really the case then an alternative method of displaying messages may be appropriate. Either way it sounds like it would be worth reviewing the logic in the app.